# To pass HttpRequestBase as a parameter

Tags: asp.net-web-api, httprequest, asp.net-apicontroller

I have a method GetIP() which takes the System.Web.HttpRequestBase as a parameter.
Could anyone help on how do I get the HttpRequestBase object.

I assume it's really basic but not able to figure out.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know what context you are in but you can get it from `HttpContext.Current.Request`. Note that `HttpContext.Current` does not work if you are hosting the web api outside of iis.

```
var request = new HttpRequestWrapper(HttpContext.Current.Request);
```